# How to properly align TabbedPanel tabs in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I've sized my tabs to take up the entire width of the app, minus a padding of 5 on each side. However, the tabs bar appears off-center from the content below it, I've included a screenshot to illustrate:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the tabs appear nudged slightly off-center towards the right

*main.py*

```py
import kivy
kivy.require('2.0.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel


class Main(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return  Main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

*my.kv*

```
<Main>
    tab_width: self.content.width / 3
    do_default_tab: False
    padding: (5, 5)
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'First Tab'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Second Tab'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Third Tab'
```

Are there any ideas/tips on what I can do to fix this so it's properly centered?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I'm guessing that the padding on the right tab is 5, so I can just subtract that from the width: `tab_width: (self.content.width - 5) / 3`

Now it looks aligned:

[image]